# why object to byte[] returns jumbled characters in java?

Tags: java, file-io, byte

```
public static byte[] objectToByteArray(Object obj) throws IOException {
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream objOut = null;
try {
    objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
    objOut.writeObject(obj);
    objOut.flush();
} finally {
    objOut.close();
    out.close();
}
return out.toByteArray();
}

Main Method :



 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
//
// System.out.println(getFileName("/home/local/ZOHOCORP/bharathi-1397/logs/bharathi-1397.csez.zohocorpin.com_2012_05_24.log",0));
try {
    throw new IOException("Error in main method");
} catch (IOException io) {
    System.out.println(new String(objectToByteArray(io.getMessage()),
        "UTF-8"));
}
//
}
```

Output : 
��

I want to convert Object to byte[] but why it returns ctrl characters like this . I didn't understand can you please help me .

Comment: I want to get "Error in main method" output from this exception object.

Comment: @kannan: So why are you serializing it? Why don't you just call `getMessage()` and stick with the string?

Comment: Instead, I feel, OP should have asked `Why "String ->Object->byte[]->String" is not returning the same readable String input?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serialization converts an object into binary data. It's fundamentally *not text data* - just like an image file isn't text data.

Your code tries to *interpret* this opaque binary data as if it were UTF-8-encoded text data. It's not, so no wonder you're seeing garbage. If you opened up an image file in a text editor, you'd see similar non-useful text. You can *try* to interpret the data as text (as you are doing) but you won't get anything useful out.

If you want to represent opaque binary data as text in a printable, reversible manner you should use base64 or hex. There are lots of libraries available to convert to base64, including [this public domain one](http://iharder.net/base64).

Comment: I want to implement a Serializable class for converting object to byte[] . is am understanding is correct?

Comment: @kannan: And your code does exactly that. It's all fine, until you try to treat that `byte[]` as UTF-8-encoded text. It's *not* UTF-8-encoded text, so don't try to interpret it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Java store the object in its own binary format when you use ObjectOutputStream. You have to use ObjectInputStream to decode data into proper Object before use.

Answer (score 0):

java api doc:
public final void writeObject(Object obj) throws IOException;
Write the specified object to the ObjectOutputStream. The class of the object, the signature of the class, and the values of the non-transient and non-static fields of the class and all of its supertypes are written. Default serialization for a class can be overridden using the writeObject and the readObject methods. Objects referenced by this object are written transitively so that a complete equivalent graph of objects can be reconstructed by an ObjectInputStream.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#writeObject(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the below approach for writing and reading the byte values from and to the file.

Convert to Hex String and then into Base64 format

To Read the file
Base64 Format

```
    byte [] encDataByteArr = hexToBytes(encData);
    byte [] dataBack = Base64.decodeBase64(encDataByteArr);
```

To Write in the file

```
    byte [] data = Base64.encodeBase64(encDataByteArr);
    returnValue = bytesToHex(data);
```

Some Utility Methods for that is as below

```
public static synchronized String bytesToHex(byte [] buf){
    StringBuffer strbuf = new StringBuffer(buf.length * 2);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
        if (((int) buf[i] & 0xff) < 0x10){
            strbuf.append("0");
        }
        strbuf.append(Long.toString((int) buf[i] & 0xff, 16));
    }
    return strbuf.toString();
}

public synchronized static byte[] hexToBytes(String hexString) {
     byte[] b = new BigInteger(hexString,16).toByteArray();     
     return b;
}
```